# How do I update my Model without updating the EF version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-4

I am working on a Legacy project which uses "EF4.0" (system.data.entity version 4.0.0.0 runtime version v4.0.30319.

There are many places in the project where properties on "context" objects are used which are not available in the newer version.

DB team has made some changes & added a few entities which I need to use in the project, now when I try to " Update Model From Database"  VS asks me to select the version of EF I want to use and gives only 2 options "Entity Framework 5.0" & "Entity Framework 6.x". But I don't want to update to these versions, as this will require code changes in many places which I want to avoid.

This is a DLL project and in app.config there are only connection string settings, no assembly configuration sections.

The version of the visual studio I am using is VS 2017 community edition(version 15.3.3).

While googling i found some articles which suggested i installing 4.x runtime via NuGet package manager, but i couldn't find any package for version 4.0
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/select-runtime-version)

How do I update my Model without updating the EF version?

Comment: Your choices are: 1.  Move to EF6, 2.  Add the new entities by hand.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, You mean that there is no way I can stay on EF4, without adding entities & other changes by hand?.
Why would MS do such a big blunder? Does it think that it's necessary to break all legacy applications just because it doesn't want to take the effort of hosting one single dll. No wonder MS is hated by all, I will be one more addition to ppl who preach against MS  stack.

Comment: If all you need is the EF4 nuget, you can find it on [this page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/).

Comment: @RobertHarvey, this page also doesn't include EF 4.0

Comment: It does.  If you click on the "Show more" link at the bottom, it will show you the older versions.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.3.1).  Click on the "Download Package" link in the Info column to the right.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did scroll till the end, the oldest version is 4.1.1.3

Comment: The version you want is 4.3.1.  It's a minor upgrade; it should be compatible with the version you're using.